# Regarding returning values of functions in Python

Tags: function, python-3.x

I was just checking this simple code to implement in another program. But it's not working and I don't understand.  Using python 3 I do

```
x = input("")
y = input("")
def f(y,x):
    if y == 0 and x != 0:
        y += 1
        return y
    elif x == 0 and y != 0:
        x += 1
        return x
print(f(y,x))
```

And I input "0" and "1" but get it prints `None`

I don't understand this part, if I enter "0" and "1" shouldn't the output be `1`?

Why is it showing none? Is something wrong with the program? If so, how can it be corrected?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Your last condition could also be false, meaning that elif block will not execute.  In python the default return value if it gets to the end of the function without hitting a return is None

For example, if you enter `y=2` and `x=1` neither the `if` condition, nor the `elif` condition match, so you just get to the end of the function, and when you get there, python returns `None`

Also, in python 3 `input` always returns a string, so you either need to convert that value to a number with `int` (or similar) or compare against strings.  For example,

```
x = int(input(""))
y = int(input(""))
def f(y,x):
    if y == 0 and x != 0:
        y += 1
        return y
    elif x == 0 and y != 0:
        x += 1
        return x
print(f(y,x))
```

though that code isn't doing any error checking, so will throw an exception if someone enters a value that cannot be converted to an int

Comment: but the input i gave was x = 0 and y = 1, so the last condition should be true and x should be incremented and returned. But the function returned none?i dont understand why?

Comment: When I run you code and type 0 and 1 I do get it to print 1.  Are you sure you tested it correctly?

Comment: i think so.i use emacs and powershell.does it have have something to do with it?

Comment: @saripallisreekar first, I don't think I've ever heard anyone using that combination!  I doubt that has anything to do with it right off the bat though.  Ah, I think I found it.  You're probably using python 3, right?  python 2 it seems input will convert the types you read in so you get ints in x and y, but python 3 leaves them as string and `'0' != 0` because string '0' is not the same as numeric 0.  Try either converting the values from input to int or compare against strings--though the incrementing won't work with strings

Comment: oh right!! i didn't to mention i use python 3, i thought the syntax would tell you . thanks, i just learned that raw_input() function of python 2.0x is completely equivalent to input() of python 3.0x..i get it now...thanks a lot!!   is the combination so weird? i read about it in some sites.

Comment: @saripallisreekar I've edited my answer to reflect the answer now that we worked it out.  Also, the strange combination to my mind was emacs and powershell.  I typically think of emacs as fairly linux-centric, and powershell, well not with a lot of overlap in a venn diagram of users